# Flutter - Image size issue

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am creating food app ui, i created card of buttons with images, now i have a problem with size of images in my buttons, they all have same height, width, padding and image size but different text wrap so they return different image scale. I already tried to make it on desired size, didn't help

```
class PopularCards extends StatelessWidget {
  PopularCards({
    super.key,
    // required this.image,
    required this.name,
    required this.image,
  });

  // Image image;
  String name;
  String image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: Container(
        width: 110,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                offset: Offset(0, 3),
              )
            ]),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white
                    ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('Hey');
                },
            child: Image.asset(image)),
              )
              ),
            Text(name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
class PopularCards extends StatelessWidget {
PopularCards({
Key? key,
required this.name,
required this.image,
}) : super(key: key);

String name;
String image;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
  child: Container(
    width: 110,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
          offset: Offset(0, 3),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(40),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print('Hey');
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 80, // Set the desired height
                width: 80, // Set the desired width
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // Set the desired padding
                child: Image.asset(
                  image,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust the image's fit
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
 }
 }
```

Try this code, wrap the image in a container and give the container height and width.

Comment: bro, i tried it, it didn't work

Comment: then create a container and inside that container, create another two container and this one container for the image and the one container for text. set the container height and width for both containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the Container height and width with:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/height
```

Answer (score 0):

create a custom button with onTap function and image child
then call the custom button in a row

code for custom button

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class customButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final Function()? onTap;
  final String name;
  const customButton({
    super.key,
    required this.imagePath,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.name,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: Image.asset(
              imagePath,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
          Text(name)
        ],
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

the showing page is

```
import 'package:custom_button/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      customButton(imagePath: 'assets/images/download1.jpeg', onTap: (){},name: 'food1',),
                      customButton(imagePath: 'assets/images/download2.jpeg', onTap: (){},name: 'food2',),
                      customButton(imagePath: 'assets/images/images.jpeg', onTap: (){},name: 'food3',),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      customButton(imagePath: 'assets/images/download1.jpeg', onTap: (){},name: 'food1',),
                      customButton(imagePath: 'assets/images/download2.jpeg', onTap: (){},name: 'food2',),
                      customButton(imagePath: 'assets/images/images.jpeg', onTap: (){},name: 'food3',),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```